# Using Switch To Seperate Outputs Of Different Letters

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

Is there any way that if a user enters any letter except T, M, or S that it will output other? Or do I have to make a case for every letter and put other? Is there any way to group them for the 'case.' Like for instance,

```
case "A - Q":
  System.out.print("Other");
  break;
```

Obviously you cant do that but something along those lines?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchPractice 
  {
  public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String employeeCode;
    System.out.print("Enter employees code: ");
    employeeCode = input.next();
    switch (employeeCode)
      {
      case "T":
          System.out.print("Technician");
          break;
      case "S":
          System.out.print("Sales");
          break;
     case "M":
          System.out.print("Marketing");
          break;
     case "?":
          System.out.print("OTHER!");
 } } }
```

Comment: you can use an `if-else` with ASCII codes and check ASCII value of the letter.

Comment: javascript tag.... again. it seems you have no idea of programming languages reality... [What is JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript)

Comment: Maybe I just wanted to post my question without it telling me 4 different times that I need to choose different tags since #java #switch #coding #case #help weren't good enough.

Comment: I only spent 2 times, the second here being a correction bearing an educational link. I hope that in the future, and for the good of all, you will take care to properly tag your questions.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/731/how-much-does-bad-tagging-impact-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Use a default case. For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchPractice 
  {
  public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String employeeCode;
    System.out.print("Enter employees code: ");
    employeeCode = input.next();
    switch (employeeCode)
      {
      case "T":
          System.out.print("Technician");
          break;
      case "S":
          System.out.print("Sales");
          break;
     case "M":
          System.out.print("Marketing");
          break;
     default:
          System.out.print("OTHER!");
          break;
     }
   }
 }
```

This default case will execute whenever the letter is not "T", "M", or "S".